# Microsoft Graph API - Get Enterprise Applications Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm wondering how to retrieve my enterprise apps with Graph API.
Is it really done by accessing the service principals? Because if I get the service principals, the display names are different than in the Azure AD UI.

Thanks!

Comment: The enterprise apps list should basically be the service principals.. If you want to identify a service principal, you'll usually want to check for a specific appId or an identifier URI.

Comment: What do you see in the Graph API vs Azure AD UI,  a screenshot and the graph API call may also help

Comment: @juunas Oh okay! but how do I filter these applications, so that I only see the enterprise apps?

[Dropdown](https://ibb.co/pPMhXqp)

Comment: I realized, that my enterprise apps are indeed service principals. Currently I'm just able to display all service principals, but I just want to display enterprise applications...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Here is how to fetch enterprise apps only in C#:

```
var servicePrincipals = await _graphServiceClient
                    .ServicePrincipals
                    .Request()
                    .GetAsync();

                foreach (var app in servicePrincipals )
                {
                    foreach (var tag in app.Tags)
                    {
                        if (tag == "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp")
                        {
                            // do something with enterprise app
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: just a shorter version with LINQ: 

servicePrincipals.Where(sp => sp.Tags.Contains("WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp"))
            .Select(sp => new
            {
                sp.Id,
                sp.DisplayName,
            }).ToList();

and bear in mind that the returned value is a page collection, you might need to fetch the next page